# GLUT compile errors with Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, opengl, compilation, glut, codeblocks

A week ago, when I first tried to work with GLUT and followed [this tutorial](http://www.sci.brooklyn.cuny.edu/~goetz/codeblocks/glut/) it worked without any errors.
Now, a week later I installed the same software, same libraries, but every time I try to compile the project I get these errors (and it highlights a line in the glut.h file):

```
obj\Debug\main.o(.text+0x1c)||In function `glutInit_ATEXIT_HACK':|
C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\GL\glut.h|486|undefined reference to `__glutInitWithExit@12'|
obj\Debug\main.o(.text+0x3d)||In function `glutCreateWindow_ATEXIT_HACK':|
C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\GL\glut.h|503|undefined reference to `__glutCreateWindowWithExit@8'|
obj\Debug\main.o(.text+0x5d)||In function `glutCreateMenu_ATEXIT_HACK':|
C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\GL\glut.h|549|undefined reference to `__glutCreateMenuWithExit@8'|
```

I uninstalled Code:Blocks, deleted the GLUT files (glut.h, glut32.dll, glut.a) and reinstalled everything, but I still get the same errors.
I'm completely sure my linker settings are OK since I've followed the tutorial. I also tried other tutorials, but get the same results, a bunch of errors.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Edit: Fixed! All that was needed was `#include <GL/gl.h>` before including `GL/glut.h`.

Comment: #pragma comment(lib, "glut32.lib") add it at the top of main.cpp

Comment: I'm using Code::Blocks, not Microsoft Visual C++

Comment: So what? It's preprocessor definition, not IDE command.

Comment: I thought #pragma was VC++ only, when I added it I only get more errors. "warning: ignoring #pragma comment"

Comment: So just open project properties and add glut32.lib to included libraries (somewhere in linker options)

Comment: It's already there, that's why I don't get this error :/

Comment: To narrow down on the problem, temporarily copy glut.a into your project folder and see if your linker can find it there. Also, what is the version of the compiler and what version of Windows are you running?

Comment: Okay, fixed it. I had to add #include <GL/gl.h> before #include <GL/glut.h>. I'm not sure why, but now all example codes I checked work if I do so.

Comment: You should change the comment to be an answer, btw it helped me out so thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to add `#include <GL/gl.h>` before `#include <GL/glut.h>`. I'm not sure why, but now all examples seem to compile just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why my comment get deleted, but in the end it did work by adding windows.h library ...