# Using glut with code blocks in Windows 7

Tags: opengl, glut

i'm a total novice with OpenGL, and I have to compile a file (my first file using opengl), the headers of the file are :

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <iostream>
```

I downloaded glut, put the glut.h in the right folder, and put the glut32lib in the right folder too (in Code Blocks).

I also linked glut32.lib in the linker settings.

But i can not compile, i have errors like this :

....\Desktop\OpenGL\OpenGL\prog3.o:prog3.cxx|| undefined reference to `__glutInitWithExit'|

Please can you help me ?

EDIT : Solution foud here : [GLUT compile errors with Code::Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885980/glut-compile-errors-with-codeblocks?rq=1#comment17448956_12885980)

All that was needed was #include  before including GL/glut.h
I don't know why...

Comment: you should move your solution in the answer. otherwise, check my solution

Answer (score 1):

This was my problem. I found solution for this problem in 2 step.

**Step 1:** follow instructions in this link: [Using OpenGL & GLUT in Code::Blocks](http://www.sci.brooklyn.cuny.edu/%7Egoetz/codeblocks/glut/)

**Step 2:** add `#include <GL/glu.h>` before `#include <GL/glut.h>`

Attention: you must create new **project**, not blank source file. Just follow how to do it in that link.